# Quicksort recursiveness

Tags: python, python-3.x, quicksort

I am trying to write a quicksort function in python, yet I am having trouble regarding the implementation of it. I understand the logic, however I've never written a recursive function before.

I've looked up YouTube tutorials, however the logic they use is often different to my logic.

As their are several ways to do a quicksort I will post my logic.
My logic is as follows:

1. A pivot is a randomly chosen item in the list
2. The pivot is moved to the right most position in the list.
3. Each item in the List is then compared to the pivot to see if it is bigger than the pivot.
4. The first item which is bigger than the pivot is designated as the FirstBigNumber.
5. The list is then iterated through again. The first item which is smaller than the pivot swaps position in the list with the FirstBigNumber, Swapped=True
6. A new FirstBigNumber is then found
7. Repeat steps 4,5,6 until pivot reached.
8. Swap pivot with FirstBigNumber.
9. The list should be sorted.

My code:

```
import random
List=[3,5,1,7,2,8]
pivot_pos=0
def getpivot(List):
    #Get pivot position
    pivot_pos=random.randint(0,len(List)-1)
    return pivot_pos

def quicksort(List,pivot_pos):
    #Calling Get Pivot function
    getpivot(List)
    print(List)
    #Obtain pivot
    pivot=List[pivot_pos]
    print("Pivot is ",pivot)
    #Swap pivot to right of list
    List[len(List)-1],List[pivot_pos]=List[pivot_pos],List[len(List)-1]
    Swapped=True
    print(List)
    #Loop through List
    for j in range(0,len(List)-1):
        print("Checking if",List[j],"is bigger than",pivot)
        #Marks first num larger than
        if List[j]>pivot and Swapped==True:
            #FirstBigNum stores the index of the First number bigger than pivot
            FirstBigNum=List[j]
            IndexOfBigNum=j
            print("BigNum is",FirstBigNum)
            #This new Big number has not been swapped
            Swapped=False
        for i in range(0,len(List)-1):
            if List[i]<pivot:
                    #Swap the index of smaller num with first big num
                    print("Swapped",List[i]," with ",List[IndexOfBigNum])
                    List[IndexOfBigNum],List[i]=List[i],List[IndexOfBigNum]
                    print(List)
                    Swapped=True
            elif List[i]<pivot:
                print("Pivot is bigger than",List[i])
                #If Value greater than pivot
                pass
            elif i == (len(List)-1):
                #We have reached the end of the List
                #So we need to swap the pivot with the FirstBigNum
                List[FirstBigNum],List[i]==List[i],List[FirstBigNum]
                print("Here")
                print(List)
            else:
                #Is equal to pivot
                pass

getpivot(List)
quicksort(List,pivot_pos)
```

The output I receive is:

```
[5, 8, 7, 2, 1, 3]
```

The output I should get is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
```

Comment: You are not using recursion anywhere, `quicksort()` doesn't call `quicksort()` anywhere.

Comment: What is `getpivot()` supposed to achieve? You never use the return value of that function. So you use the *global* variable `pivot_pos`, which always stays at `0`.

Comment: You actually *print* the chosen pivot position, had you noticed that it always prints 0?

Comment: Calling `getpivot(List)` doesn't have the effect of modifying the global value of `pivot_pos` (and modifying global variables wouldn't be recommended anyway). You seem to have a basic misunderstanding of how function calls work in Python. Perhaps you should clarify your understanding of functions before you try to implement quicksort.

Comment: Also, `List[FirstBigNum],List[i]==List[i],List[FirstBigNum]` makes no sense since you are using `==` rather than `=`

Comment: Next, you aren't actually implementing quicksort. There is no 'first big value' pointer in quicksort. In quicksort, you pick a pivot, and every value smaller is kept before the pivot, every value that is bigger is moved after the pivot. So you handle **all** elements in your array. You then divide your array into two sub-arrays and you apply the same algorithm to each sub-array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a standard implementation of Quicksort using recursion with the Lomuto partition. I included a main driver with a random list so you can test it:

```
import random


def quick_sort(a, l=0, r=None):
    # Recusrion requires a Base Case
    if r is None :
        r = len(a) - 1
    if l >= r :
        return 0
    # If the Base Case is not encountered then proceed to partion
    s = lomuto_partition(a, l, r)
    # call quicksort recursively
    quick_sort(a, l, s-1)
    quick_sort(a, s+1, r)
    return a


def lomuto_partition(a, l, r):
    p = a[l]
    s = l
    for i in range(l+1, r+1) :
        if a[i] < p :
            s += 1
            a[s], a[i] = a[i], a[s]
    a[l], a[s] = a[s], a[l]
    return s


def random_seq(n=10, lo=0, hi=100):
    seq = []
    for i in range(n):
        seq.append(random.randint(lo, hi))
    return seq


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    n = 16
    print('n:', n)

    a = random_seq(n)
    print("Unsorted Random List: ", a)
```

I hope this helps